# JS not displaying values in asp Textbox Nor Input

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

```
<asp:TextBox ID="DataBus" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

This is a textbox element that is not receiving any variable from js.

`$("#DataBus").val('hi');`

I tried the below html code, still not working

```
<input ID="DataBus" type="text" runat="server"/>
```

Elements are not read only, and the code is right.
I've been struggling for hours to understand what may be happening.

[image: Value not displayed]

Comment: check console for error?

Comment: Have you made sure that you jQuery is included in your page and do you get any console errors

Comment: Try `$("#DataBus").attr("value", "Hi");`

Comment: I tried this , it didn't work and yet i don't want to change the value permanently. The whole js is working just fine its processing arrays yet not displaying.

Comment: the error console is displaying this : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found), yet all the js files are included and working without the display of variables in the textbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue will most likely be due to the way ASP.NET WebForms auto generates ID names for all controls upon rendering the output.

You will need to tell it to use a static ID, that way your jquery should work correctly.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="DataBus" runat="server" ClientIDMode="static"></asp:TextBox>
```

Also, ensure you have jquery installed properly.

Not sure why the plain input one isn't working, other than jquery not installed OR there's a conflict somewhere. See my fiddle of it working on a plain input field.

[JsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xer7h7ty/)

Regards

Craig

Comment: I removed everything and i pasted the code you wrote in the JsFiddle Demo. its displaying and the page is refreshing by itself

Comment: @Karimb are you using an ASP.NET button? If so this is what will be causing the postback. OR if you have added **runat="server"** to the HTML input.

Comment: i used an asp button and the button you set and both didn't work. i removed the class submit and still it is refreshing the page. there is no other js script included in the asp file.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time

Comment: @Karimb Take a look at the following, will point you in the right direction... Don't want to do all the work for you :P [link](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)